# Rendering of HTML elements along the z-axis

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get to grips with how `html` elements are rendered along the z-axis and on the whole it is making sense.

When no element has a z-index, elements are stacked in this order (from bottom to top):

1 - Background and borders of the root element
  2 - Descendant blocks in the normal flow, in order of appearance (in HTML)
  3 - Descendant positioned elements, in order of appearance (in HTML)

Importantly, different stacking contexts can exist; for example through the use of positioning or from nested elements.

This all makes sense to me. At least I thought it did until I tried putting it into practice.

**CSS**:

```
.element-one {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: pink;
}
.child-one {
  border: 5px solid red;
  margin-top: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
.element-two {
  border: 5px solid orange;
  height: 25rem;
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/29/05/34/new-york-1867569_1280.jpg");
  margin-top: -30px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<body>
  <div class="element-one">I am element one<p class="child-one">Child One</p></div>
  <div class="element-two">I am element two</div>

</body>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahardiman35/nndqqmba/8/)

Why does 'child-one' sit stacked above 'element-two' even though it comes before it in the normal flow (point 2 above). Especially given the fact that 'child-one' is also a nested element. What confuses me further, is that it is not the whole element that is stacked on-top, but just the content, i.e. the red border of 'child-one' is stacked behind 'element-two'.

Comment: Your Q&A would probably be more useful if you included the relevant parts of your HTML & CSS and a picture in your question and not just the link to the fiddle.

Comment: @jcaron thank you, I have done as you have suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is not immediately obvious, and even a Google search does not immediately come up with a crystal clear solution.

The answer does indeed lie in the concept of 'stacking context'. Moreover, in how each element is rendered, or painted, within that context.

With some close inspection, the answer can be found in the [W3C Specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html). Specifically Appendix E.2 "Painting Order". Here you can follow a painting algorithm, which describes the painting order for the descendants of an element generating a stacking context; in my specific example the `body` tag.

The page given in the question is rendered that way because all in-flow, non-positioned, block-level elements are rendered in a unitary fashion; that is, rather than the entirety of each element beginning rendered 'in-turn', the backgrounds and borders of all the elements within the stacking context are rendered together, as are the contents (the docs refer to this as "atomic" rendering).

> 4. For all its in-flow, non-positioned, block-level descendants in tree order: If the element is a block, list-item, or other block equivalent:
>
>    1. background color of element.
>    2. background image of element.
>    3. border of element.